# how to select all records from one table that not exist in relation table?

Tags: sql, database

ObjectClass1

```
OBID | Name

0001 | ob01
0002 | ob02
```

Relation1

```
RELID|LEFTOBID|RIGHTOBID|CLASS1|CLASS2

R001 |0001    |000X     |ObjectClass1|ObjectClass2
```

Now What I want to find out is how to write a query to find out that relation does not exists for OBID 0002

Comment: Add some more sample table data, and also specify the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Use `not exists` as :

```
select *
  from ObjectClass1 o
 where not exists
   ( select 1 from Relation1 r where r.LEFTOBID = o.OBID );
```

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/UKCCB89547)

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL
SELECT  *
FROM    ObjectClass1    obj
LEFT JOIN
        Relation1       rel
  on    obj.OBID = rel.LEFTOBID
WHERE   rel.LEFTOBID is null
```